# Confused about the current status of Javascript's '.keyCode property'

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard, frontend, deprecated

Cannot find a real solid answer to my question. Is Javascript's property 'KeyboardEvent.keyCode' deprecated? Jetbrains IDE's, 'PHP-STORM' and 'WEB-STORM, say it is deprecated, however, they offer no alternative. Since my IDE told me it was deprecated I googled it and found that W3Schools, at url: (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_keycode.asp), does not state that it is depricated. From reading their page, which is dedicated specifically to the .keyCode property, one would think it is good for use. So again, is it depricated? And if it is deprecated then is their an alernative for use, or a work around that returns the value of a key that the user presses?

event.keyCode;

Comment: The `key` property is an appropriate alternative for a lot of cases. Which keys do you need to recognize?

Comment: Writing a script that allows the user to tab inside of a textbox, so just tab really.

Comment: Just FYI key is exactly what I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode):

> The deprecated KeyboardEvent.keyCode read-only property represents a
>   system and implementation dependent numerical code identifying the
>   unmodified value of the pressed key. This is usually the decimal ASCII
>   (RFC 20) or Windows 1252 code corresponding to the key. If the key
>   can't be identified, this value is 0.
>
> You should avoid using this if possible; it's been deprecated for some
>   time. Instead, you should use KeyboardEvent.code, if it's implemented.
>   Unfortunately, some browsers still don't have it, so you'll have to be
>   careful to make sure you use one which is supported on all target
>   browsers.

Comment: After researching, .KeyboardEvent.code is definatly where W3C or whatever is heading, but as of now My IDE doesn't even support KeyboardEvent.code...

Answer (score 0):

The .key property as stated in a comment above, worked for me as it was not depricated and usable in all browsers I am testing with (chrome 77.0.3865.90[desktop] and 77.0.3865.92[Iphone]6s what ever safari is on my Iphone6s, firefox 68.0.1 and through the jetbrains android emulator[firefox 68.1.1] as well as on windows 10 with IE10 and edge]. keyCode only had some minor hiccups with chrome, for some reason I got a type error with it sometimes. To be honest I was really hoping for a goo answer on this topic, but its been a few days now and I have got nothing. Since there is very little out there on this subject I thought I would throw out what worked for me, however; key wont work for all apps. I have read that it isnt a good option for keyboards specific to non-English languages as it returns the name of the key in string format, rather than a ASCII code.